Interrupting WebAssembly module inside WebWorker
I have a wasm module that I instantiate inside a WebWorker.
At some point in time from the main thread (browser) I'm sending to the worker's thread a post-message to enforce the worker giving a control flow to the wasm module.
The wasm module initiates a long-running computational task, that could potentially be infinite. The module from time to time reports it's progress by returning control flow back to the JavaScript function imported into the module. If this function returns a flag-value back to the wasm module, the module interrupts it's task.
I would like to have a way to interrupt wasm's execution from the WebWorker's host thread (from the browser main thread).
I didn't find a good way to do this so far, and would like to ask your opinions if there are any sustainable workarounds I can utilizes.
The main difficulty is that whenever wasm execution is in progress, the WebWorker is not able to handle incoming messages from it's host. As such I can't send a message to WebWorker to set an interruption flag that I would use when the wasm module invoking it's report function.
Some workarounds I considered:

From the wasm report function send a post message to the host. The host, in turn, would decide to terminate the entire WebWorker with the wasm module inside. It works fine, but I don't want to terminate the entire WebWorker. I would like to reuse it in the future.
Use SharedArrayBuffer and atomics to share an interruption flag between the WebWorker thread and it's host thread. This solution probably should work, but these features require crossOriginIsolated. I'm not sure if my web server would allow me to configure response headers. I'm also unsure if using of atomics would be sustainable in general.

So, the solution that would work for me is to utilize any javascript API available inside the WebWorker global context through which I can share a flag between the host thread and the web worker's thread, and though which I can read the flag's state synchronously inside my report function. For example, IndexedDB would be ok, unless it supports asynchronous requests only.
